# How can i get out of this nested while loop? (Python)

Tags: python

Good afternoon! I'm a beginner in coding and i'm trying to do an exercise done for Python.
Building a nested While Loop, i'm with a bug in my little he last line of the code says `elif continua == "N"or "n": i = -1`   and it should exit all the while loop (the nested and the first one), since i=-1 and the condition for the while loop to work in this code is i > 0 (or at least this is my purpose doing this line of coding.). But all of the sudden the loop starts again and i dont know why.
Can someone help me to get out of this loop?

```
b = 0

i = 1
valorTotal = 0.00
Audiencia = True
listadevalores = []
while i >= 0:

    a = int(input("Digite a quantidade de itens de audiência que serão calculados: "))
    i=a+1
    while i>1: 
        a=0
        v = float(input ("Insira os valores: "))
        valorTotal = valorTotal + v
        b+=1
        i-=1
        listadevalores.append(v)
        if b>1:
            if listadevalores[b-1] < listadevalores[b-2]:
            Audiencia = False
      else: 
        if Audiencia == True
        print ("Audiência sempre crescente. Média de audiência: ", (valorTotal/b))
        elif Audiencia == False
        print ("Audiência nem sempre crescente. Média de audiência: ",(valorTotal/b))
        continua = input ("Deseja continuar? S/N")
        if continua == "S"or "s":
            b=0
            valorTotal = 0.00
             Audiencia = True
             listadevalores = []
             i=0
        elif continua == "N"or "n":
           i = -1
```

Comment: Have you considered just using `break`?

Comment: As an aside both `continua == "S"or "s"` and `continua == "N"or "n"` are both incorrect.  For instance, to check for"S" or "s" you can use `continua == "S" or continua == "s"`  Also, `continua == "S"or "s"` is always True, so the lines in the condition will always be executed.

Comment: @Erich `break` would only break the nested loop, not the outer loop.

Comment: In addition to DarrylG's comment, you can also use `continua in ("S", "s")`

Comment: ```continua``` is not defined.

Comment: @Sujay it is. There is an input assigned to `continua`

Comment: @DarrylG i changed it and fixed (and understood why). Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 2):

There were several errors in your code.

- missing `:` at the end of `if` or `elif` statemennts
- several incorrect intendations (maybe a formating issue while copy paste)
- You cannot chain bool checks lile `continua == "N" or "n"` use `continua  == 'n' or continua  == 'N'` or in this case even better `continua.lower() == 'n'`

You are searching for `break`. Here is a working version of your code:

```
b = 0

i = 1
valorTotal = 0.00
Audiencia = True
listadevalores = []
while i >= 0:

    a = int(input("Digite a quantidade de itens de audiência que serão calculados: "))
    i=a+1
    while i>1: 
        a=0
        v = float(input ("Insira os valores: "))
        valorTotal = valorTotal + v
        b+=1
        i-=1
        listadevalores.append(v)
        if b>1:
            if listadevalores[b-1] < listadevalores[b-2]:
                Audiencia = False
    else: 
      if Audiencia == True:
          print ("Audiência sempre crescente. Média de audiência: ", (valorTotal/b))
      elif Audiencia == False:
          print ("Audiência nem sempre crescente. Média de audiência: ",(valorTotal/b))
      continua = input ("Deseja continuar? S/N")
      if continua.lower() ==  "s":
          b=0
          valorTotal = 0.0
          Audiencia = True
          listadevalores = []
          i=0
      elif continua.lower() == "n":
          break
```

The flow of your code is a bit hard to read. Especially it is difficult to understand what your i,a,b variables are doing. Here is a second version which showes how to make your code a bit easier to understand.

```
def floatInput(input_str):
    number = None
    while not number:
        try:
            number = float(input (input_str)) 
        except:
            print('not a float number in Portuguese')
    return number
    

while True:
    a = int(floatInput("Digite a quantidade de itens de audiência que serão calculados: "))
    listadevalores = []
    
    for i in range(a):
        v = floatInput("Insira os valores: ")
        listadevalores.append(v)
    
    mean = sum(listadevalores) / len(listadevalores)
    
    if sorted(listadevalores) == listadevalores:
        print ("Audiência sempre crescente. Média de audiência: ", (mean))
    else:
        print ("Audiência nem sempre crescente. Média de audiência: ",(mean))
    
    continua = input ("Deseja continuar? S/N")
    
    if continua.lower() ==  "s":
        continue
    
    break
```

Here is some explanation to the improved parts.

**Inputs**

The input may be not a number although it is needed. This might create crashes. The exception for strings that cannot be parsed are handled by `try: ... except:` The second while loop is moved in a seperate function and out of the main flow to make it easier to read. Also it now can be called several times without the need for reapeating code. The `while` loop is self terminating when `number` gets a valid value.

**Variabels**

The meaning of i,a and b are not directly self explanatory. Also they are set at different positions in the code. You already have all information you need in the list.
Ascending lists by definition does not change when they get sorted. We can use this trick to check if the sorted list is the original list `sorted(listadevalores) == listadevalores`. So we don't need to work on the list elements.
The mean value can be calculated by dividing the sum of all list elements, using the build in `sum` by the lengt of the list `sum(listadevalores) / len(listadevalores)`.

Comment: You should try to explain everything that you changed

Comment: He may not have learned functions yet as part of his study plan. In most lessons guides, looping comes before modularity. And probably is also not familiar with try and excepts or would know what the sorted function does.

But it is a vast improvement.

Comment: @Hofbr thats why it`s the second solution. To show different concepts as a starting point for deeper understanding and helping OP to improve his skills. But I added some explanations for the major changes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have wrong indentation in question. Please fix this.

Also, it may help you:
create variable that tells your loops to proceed and set it to False when you need to stop the loops. An example:

```
loop = True

while your_condition and loop:

    // Do some stuff here

    while your_next_condition and loop:

        // Do some stuff here

        if something_happened:
            loop = False
```

Comment: This really helped me on building while loops. Thanks.

Comment: @LorenzoFioreze but be aware that creating complicated loop conditions does make your code complicated. If there is a way to solve the problem with re-structuring and `break`s it could be a better way to go.